# Tail Recursive Tree Traversal without Loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, traversal, tail-recursion

I want to traverse the following tree structure tail recursively **without falling back on loops**:

```
const o = {x:0,c:[{x:1,c:[{x:2,c:[{x:3},{x:4,c:[{x:5}]},{x:6}]},{x:7},{x:8}]},{x:9}]};

        0
       / \
      1   9
    / | \ 
   2  7  8
 / | \
3  4  6
   |
   5
```

The desired result: `/0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9`

I guess a closure is required to enable tail recursion. I've tried this so far:

```
const traverse = o => {
  const nextDepth = (o, index, acc) => {
    const nextBreadth = () => o["c"] && o["c"][index + 1]
     ? nextDepth(o["c"][index + 1], index + 1, acc)
     : acc;

    acc = o["c"]
     ? nextDepth(o["c"][0], index, acc + "/" + o["x"]) // not in tail pos
     : acc + "/" + o["x"];

    return nextBreadth();
  };

  return nextDepth(o, 0, "");
};

traverse(o); // /0/1/2/3/4/5/7/9
```

The siblings are not traversed properly. How can this be done?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47932/recursion-vs-iteration-of-tree-structure

Comment: You cannot traverse a tree using only tailrecursion unless you want to manually maintain a stack.

Comment: How would you write it with loops? Try that first, then convert the loop into a tailrecursive function.

Comment: @Bergi What a pity! I tried this for hours without any success. I thought maybe with closures handling `index` as a free variable could be a viable option. That would be probably the mimicked stack you speak of.

Comment: @Bergi are you sure it's not possible? What if you recurse over the "levels" of the tree (selecting all relevant children to send in to the recursion for the next level), instead of recursing over individual nodes?

Comment: @Magne Then you've built a breadth-first search with a queue. OP wants a depth-first search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Bergi wrote if you manually maintain stack the solution is straightforward.

```js
const o = {x:0,c:[{x:1,c:[{x:2,c:[{x:3},{x:4,c:[{x:5}]},{x:6}]},{x:7},{x:8}]},{x:9}]}

const traverse = g => {
  const dfs = (stack, head) => (head.c || []).concat(stack)
  
  const loop = (acc, stack) => {
    if (stack.length === 0) {
     return acc
    }

    const [head, ...tail] = stack
    return loop(`${acc}/${head.x}`, dfs(tail, head))
  }
  
  return loop('', [g])
}

console.log(traverse(o))
console.log(traverse(o) === '/0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9')
```

Comment: Very nice, full tail recursive solution, thanks! Handling your own stack doesn't seem to be so hard.

Comment: One of the best question/answers I've seen on SO in a very long time.